# Grabbing html from a specific website in android

Tags: java, android, httpclient

i've tried grabbing html source of this webapge http://www.mindef.gov.sg/content/imindef/press_room/official_releases/nr/2013/jan/22jan13_nr.html . however i encounted error as it responded with a different type of html as compared to what i am able to see from the browser. it seems like doing a httopost to the web and on the app result in different type of respond

```
address="http://www.mindef.gov.sg/content/imindef/press_room/official_releases/nr/2013/jan/22jan13_nr.html";
        String result = "";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    //  httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.single-cookie-header", true);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(httpclient.getParams(),  "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-ca; LG-P505R Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1");           
InputStream is = null;
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet (address);

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            InputStream is = null;
```

Comment: Ummm, why are you using HTTP POST for getting the page source?

Comment: If you are not sending data to the page, you should use a `GET` request, not a `POST`. That said, if you don't explain what you receive you are less likely to get the correct help.

Comment: hi guys, sorry my fault here. I'm just grabbig html source from teh web. httpget should be the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
    URLConnection  cn= new URL(url).openConnection();

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( cn.getInputStream() ) );
```

Read input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're getting a mobile version of the site. If you extend the URL to include `?siteversion=pc` you should get the page as served to a browser on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.url.com");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) builder.append(line);
```

Then, the page source should be in `builder`.